# Using SQL Server stored procedures with empty resultsets in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I use PHP 5.4 with Microsofts 3.0 drivers to execute stored procedures in SQL server 2008. It works fine until I execute a procedure that isn't returning any result as it is just doing an update. The error message I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.
```

The procedure that isn't working boils down to this simple code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_communication_increase_trials]
    @comId bigint = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT @comId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Communication SET CommunicationTrials = CommunicationTrials + 1 WHERE id = @comId;
    END;

END
```

The PHP-code barfs at the `fetchAll` method when executing the procedure above:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    do {
        $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($rowset) {
            $results[] = $rowset;
        }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

}
return $results;
```

However, adding a simple select after the update-statement in the procedure makes it work, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to add a boolean as an argument to the method that is executing the procedure and returning the results to indicate if a returning result set is expected. The boolean is default set to `TRUE` unless explicitly specified to be `FALSE`.

This way the `fetchAll` method isn't called when told not to.

```
if ($stmt->execute() && $do_return_rowsets) {
    do {
        $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($rowset) {
            $results[] = $rowset;
        }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

}
```

It's perhaps not more than fair that the contract between the PHP code and the procedure specifies that a rowset is to be returned or not.